# Remove charset in Content-Type header

Tags: nginx

In what way the charset for the `Content-Type` response be removed?

```
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
```

The nginx.conf file is already set to

```
http {
   sendfile on;
   tcp_nopush on;
   tcp_nodelay on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;
   types_hash_max_size 2048;
   charset off;

   server {
          listen 80;
          server_name ~. "";
          location / {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
          }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to force remove the charset?

Comment: Is this header generated by nginx or comes from an upstream?

Comment: From the server running on port 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
    map $upstream_http_content_type $stripped_content_type {
        "~^(.+);charset="  $1;
        default            $upstream_http_content_type;
    }

    server {
        ...
        location / {
            ...
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
            add_header Content-Type $stripped_content_type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also needed to do this, but was unable to get your example to work, it fails with: nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable